# Ocultar campos dependiendo del valor en una lista

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Estoy trabajando el laravel 5.5

Tengo esta lista en mi formulario, Los valores que muestra son FISICO y VIRTUAL:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_uso', 'Uso', App\Usos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['class'=>'chosen']) !!}
```

y quisiera si se escoje en la lista el valor Fisico, se muestren los siguientes campos :

```
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'marca', 'Marca', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'modelo', 'Modelo', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'mac', 'Mac', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'serial', 'Serial', ['required']) !!}
```

y en caso de que la opcion seleccionada sea VIRTUAL, se oculten.

Me parece que quedaria mejor si los pudiera cambiar a un Radiobutton, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Agradezco vuestra ayuda.

Feliz día.

EDIT:

[image: Despues de la modificacion]

Así es que como queda despues de la modificación.

Comment: primero debes capturar el value del select y dependiendo del valor mandas al input el atributo hidden

Comment: Tienes algun ejemplo con el que lo pueda aplicar ? Es que no lo entiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes identificar el evento cuando se cambie la opción seleccionada de tu lista y en base al valor seleccionado, ocultar/mostrar los campos.

Para el caso que mencionas, puedes agregar el atributo "id" a la lista de usos y poder identificarla dentro de tu página, por ejemplo:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_uso', 'Uso', App\Usos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['id' => 'listaUsos', 'class'=>'chosen']) !!}
```

para el caso de los campos, como son varios elementos, puedes agregarles un atributo de clase personalizado, por ejemplo:

```
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'marca', 'Marca', ['required', 'class' => 'requerido-con-fisico']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'modelo', 'Modelo', ['required', 'class' => 'requerido-con-fisico']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'mac', 'Mac', ['required', 'class' => 'requerido-con-fisico']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'serial', 'Serial', ['required', 'class' => 'requerido-con-fisico']) !!}
```

y agregar el siguiente código de jquery en tu página:

```
$(function() {
    $("#listaUsos").change(function(){
        if($("option:selected", this).text() == 'FISICO'){
            $(".requerido-con-fisico").show();
        }else{
            $(".requerido-con-fisico").hide();                
        }
    });
});
```

con esto, al cambiar la opción de la lista, si el texto es "FISICO", todos los elementos con la clase "requerido-con-fisico" se mostrarán en pantalla, en caso contrario se ocultarán.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda, Mira que agregue la funcion dentro de un campo script

<script>
     $(function() {
    $("#listaUsos").change(function(){
        if($("option:selected", this).text() == 'Fisico'){
            $(".requerido-con-fisico").show();
        }else{
            $(".requerido-con-fisico").hide();                
        }
    });
});
  </script>

Pero no me los esconde cuando escojo el valor de la lista.

Comment: Debes incluir la librería de jquery. Si no la tienes, intenta agregando la siguiente línea a tu proyecto:


    `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>`


Solo asegurate de agregarla antes de la función para ocultar/mostrar los campos, sino no funcionara.

Comment: Hola buen día, Funciono a la perfección, Pero tengo 2 dudas, realizandole este cambio a los campos, cambiaron su longitud en la pantalla, hay alguna posibilidad de dejarla como estaba antes.

Me explico, antes ese campo era largisimo, pero ahora, es como la 4ta parte.

Y la otra pregunta es, Existe la posibilidad de esconder todo el campo como tal ? Porque con este cambio, se esconde el textbox, pero si quisiera que se escondiera tambien el nombre del campo.

Te agradezco demasiado, así no mas me a funcionado de maravilla.

Mil gracias nuevamente :)

Comment: Puedes mandar el ejemplo del código con el cual estas mostrando los nombres de los campos.

Comment: En el form como tal de esta forma {!! Form::myInput('text', 'marca', 'Marca', ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico']) !!}.

Comment: Agrege la imagen de como quedo modificado a la publicación.

Comment: Al momento de agregarle ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico'] al campo, Se pierde el formato que traee originalmente, que e sun formato chosen.
select.chosen {
    height: 0!important;
    opacity: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    display: block!important;
}

Comment: Veo que usas un componente para armar tanto la etiqueta como el textbox, en ese caso tendrías que checar la definición de tu componente "myInput", para que al agregar clases, también se los asignes a la etiqueta.

Sobre el formato que mencionas, aunque se agregue la clase "chosen" a los textbox, no verías cambios, ya que tu declaración solo aplica para elementos "select" ('select.chosen'). Puedes agregar un atributo style para ocupar todo el espacio del navegador: `{!! Form::myInput('text', 'marca', 'Marca', ['required', 'class' => 'requerido-con-fisico', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}`.

Comment: Agregandole el style funciono, Una ultima cosa, Me podrias indicar como hago que un campo tipo lista sea requerido ? Lo tengo de esta forma :

{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 
               'Servidor padre: Escojer unicamente los que esten marcador con - 1', [0 => 'Escoge una opción'] +
                App\Servidores::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(hostname, ' - ', id_uso) AS hostname_version"), "id")-> pluck('hostname_version', 'id')->toArray(),       
                null, 
               ['required','class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}

Toma ese val por defecto.

Comment: Toma por fedecto este valor 'Escoge una opción', en vez de requerir que se escoja algun valor de la lista.

Y sabes como podria esconder todo el texbox ?

Comment: Intenta quitando el primer arreglo con el índice cero y agregando el atributo "placeholder":  `{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 'Servidor padre: Escojer unicamente los que esten marcador con - 1', App\Servidores::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(hostname, ' - ', id_uso) AS hostname_version"), "id")-> pluck('hostname_version', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['required','class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}`. Para esconder todo el textbox, como te comente, debes checar tu definición del componente "myInput" para que agregues clases a la etiqueta.

Comment: Listo Richard, Mil gracias amigo :)